# Unable to show least node of multi level expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable list view with 4 levels of elements, when I click on the last element to expand, it doesn't expand at all, I am not able to see even one item but it has more items.

I tried to set layout height dynamically, but i don't know how to get real children items height

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use setOnGroupCollapseListener method

Answer (score 1):

set listeners like that:

```
int lastExpandedGroupPosition;

    // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;

            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped (Close) listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is lastExpandedGroupPosition initialized ?